# Visual Studio 2010: Stop debugger at breakpoint overnight = Freeze after the next step

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am experiencing freeze issues with Visual Studio if I leave the debugger at a breakpoint overnight and then return the next day to continue (i.e. F10).

What happens is that not only Visual Studio freezes but the entire computer hangs as well forcing me to restart. This occurs on a quad core computer which means VS is basically occupying the CPU for all cores.

Is there something I can do with stupid bugs like this or do I really have to avoid leaving a debugging process stop at a breakpoint for an extended period of time? I actually do need to do something like this because there are times it'd take hours for a certain break point to hit.

Thanks.

Edit: I am debugging a local project that connects to a remote SQL server. I never have problem with it if I leave the breakpoint for an hour or so. The freeze only occurs when I leave it overnight.

Edit2: Problem also occurs if I kill the debugger instead of continuing with it after an overnight breakpoint.

Comment: Just a suggestion avoiding your question - why not use some kind of a log instead of waiting hours for the application hitting a certain breakpoint?

Comment: Not enough information.  I've left the VS debugger at a breakpoint over many hours without problem.  What are you debugging?  Is it a service or system process of some sort?

Comment: Is it possible that something is going on when you break, that suffers from some kind of timeout? Maybe a connection to a service or a database or some asynchronous operation?

Comment: It could be, but the same problem also occurs if I try to kill the debugger with the stop button.

Comment: Re S_F: Debuggers are very powerful in that they allow a great deal of direct control over what happens at a given point of the execution. Namely, I don't need to guess what type of information I need to print to a log and I can fetch most if not all of the information that is available in that time point. Powerful debuggers like the one in VS also allows the user to backtrack and alter the steps of the execution to test out solutions to problems.

Comment: Is the remote sql box being restarted overnight?

Comment: I have the same issue. Remote SQL is not involved in my case, I've seen it happen on several different projects of varying complexity. Usually I hit a breakpoint, analyse the callstack, head home for the night forgetting that I left it at the breakpoint, then when I either kill the debugger or resume it the next day, the whole system hangs.

Comment: Keep calm and install windows again,

Answer (score -1):

Create a Test Project that is very simple that connect to a remote sql server and this will determine if its the project   or the computer. My first guess would be you need to reinstall windows.